# RESTful web service using PHP

Tags: php, web-services, restful-url

We have data in our database as `book-id`, `title`, `year`, `price`, `author`, `category`. We need to retrieve data from the database using php. We can retrieve data of a book with `book-id=123` by giving the url: `www.localhost/books/?book-id=123` through `$_GET` method. But my requirement is I want to see that information of book with `book-id=123` when I give the url: `www.localhost/books/123`
I am using a Wamp server for this.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: This helped me immensely when I had to create my own: http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php

Answer (score 0):

You will have to enable mod_rewrite for your Apache. After this you can use a rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /$1/?id=$2
```

in your .htaccess File. This rule would internally redirect  books/123 to books/?id=123.

See also: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches here.

**The wrong approach**:
One could be to use your webserver to provide the URL `rewrite rules` (like the other answer says for `Apache Web Server`). As the other answer suggests. But that is not the right thing to do for application portability because your application depends on your web server type to route URLs.

**The right approach**:
The right approach is to do application level routing and keep the routing overhead as minimum to the web server as possible. Just direct your web server to point to one entry point of your PHP application (like one `index.php`). It would mean a `regex` matching for the incoming URL paths. I would suggest using an existing framework which provides routing capabilities like `Laravel` to prevent any missing corner cases in `regex`.

For e.g, if you really want to implement yourself, what you could do is follow the following steps:

```
$booksRoute = /^(\/)?books(\/)?[0-9]+(\/)?$/;
route($booksRoute, function() {
   // process in the closure function
});
```